# Z-Index issue in IE7 with dropdown and page elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, z-index, drop-down-menu

I've spent about a week trying to troubleshoot this - tried just about every combination I can think using postion: relative and z-index.

My test site http://pma.916networks.com looks fine in all browsers except IE7 (or IE8 with compatibility mode on).

My CSS dropdown menu hides behind an image slideshow and some buttons, both of which have some z-index stuff going on for text overlay and image slideshow.

How can I make these two elements (dropdown nav and page elements) get into the same z-index ranking so I can rank the dropdown menu higher?

Thanks in advance, this issue is killing me!
BFC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index:9999;` to your `#top-header` div to position your top nav above everything else in your document.